# Passing string to Custom Authorize MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have just created a custom Authorize method so that a User on the website I am building, is only able to see his/her view.

```
public class UserAuthorize : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public string Username { get; set; }

    protected override bool AuthorizeCore(HttpContextBase httpContext)
    {
        var authorized = base.AuthorizeCore(httpContext);
        if (!authorized)
        {
            return false;
        }

        string username = httpContext.User.Identity.Name;

        if(new RolesBL().IsUserInRole(username, 1))//1 is Admin
        {
            return true;
        }

        return Username.Equals(username);
    }
}
```

I am having trouble passing through the data from the controller to this method

```
[UserAuthorize(Username = username)]
public ActionResult Details(string username)
{
    User u = new UsersBL().GetUser(username);
    return View(u);
}
```

How can I pass the username in the View's parameter to the Authorize method as well.

Thanks and Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The arguments in an `[Attribute]` declaration are all defined at compile-time, and must therefore be constants. You can't "pass in" the run-time value of an action parameter.

Besides which, the attribute will be used prior to the action method being invoked (to determine whether the action *can* be invoked) - and so that parameter won't even be instantiated.

You might however be able to access the `username` value within the `UserAuthorize` attribute implementation, since the `httpContext` parameter gives you access to the request details, which presumably contains the user name as part of the query string.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a case where using authorization makes sense. You should instead prevent the user from being able to pass in an argument to override the user that they are logged in as.

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    User u = new UsersBL().GetUser(this.User.Identity.Name);
    return View(u);
}
```

Your query then acts as a filter to ensure only the logged in user's information is seen.

If you need a super user to be able to view/edit each user, then you would need to use a role to ensure that only users in that role can edit other users. But in that case, the standard `AuthorizeAttribute` will suffice.

```
public ActionResult Details()
{
    User u = new UsersBL().GetUser(this.User.Identity.Name);
    return View(u);
}

[Authorize(Roles = "SuperUser")]
public ActionResult Details(string username)
{
    User u = new UsersBL().GetUser(username);
    return View(u);
}
```